# Evento JQuery no primeiro input executa em todos os outros

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá, estou com um problema com inputs, vejam o código abaixo:

```js
// fixar descrição do campo
var campo = $('.campo-formulario');
var descricao = $('.descricao-campo');

campo.on('input',function(){
   if(campo.val().length > 0){
       descricao.addClass('descricao-fixa');
   } else{
       descricao.removeClass('descricao-fixa');
   }
});
```

Ele trava a label do meu input quando tem algo digitado nele, e até funciona quando estou com apenas um input, mas quando tenho mais de um começa o problema.

Quando eu ativo o primeiro input e digito alguma coisa, o script executa em todos os outros campos, quando ele deveria funcionar só no primeiro.

Outra coisa que acontece, é que o script só ativa quando eu digito no primeiro campo, se eu digitar em qualquer outro, ele não funciona.

O que eu preciso exatamente é que só a label do input que eu digitei fixasse quando eu digitasse algo, por exemplo:

- digitei no input 1, a label subiu e fixou
- Label do input 2, 3, 4... continua embaixo.

Já procurei em tudo mas não consigo achar uma solução, me ajudem por favor, isso é meu projeto final de um curso de informática.

Segue o HTML e CSS:

```css
input {
outline: none;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
height: 40px;
padding: 0 15px;
font-family: 'Texto';
color: #222;
font-size: 105%;
background: none;
}

.container-campo {
width: 49%;
position: relative;
}

.descricao-campo {
position: absolute;
left: 15px;
top: 7px;
transition: all .2s;
cursor: text;
}

.descricao-fixa {
top: -10px;
left: 8px;
transition: all .2s;
z-index: 3;
background: #fff;
padding: 0 5px;
font-size: 80%;
font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus ~ .descricao-campo {
top: -10px;
left: 8px;
transition: all .2s;
z-index: 3;
background: #fff;
padding: 0 5px;
font-size: 80%;
color: dodgerblue;
font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus {
border: 1.5px solid dodgerblue;
}

.campos-dados-produto {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.dados-produto {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="campos-dados-produto">
  <div class="container-campo">
    <input type="text" name="codigo" class="campo-formulario" id="codigo" required>
    <label class="descricao-campo" for="codigo">Código</label>
  </div>
  <div class="container-campo">
    <input type="text" name="descricao" class="campo-formulario" id="descricao" required>
    <label class="descricao-campo" for="descricao">dsdds</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse seletor `$('.descricao-campo');` se applica nos seus 2 campos. Quando voce faz isso na sua funcao `descricao.addClass('descricao-fixa');` o que acontece e que voce esta manipulando todos os elementos com a classe `.descricao-campo`, por isso afeta os 2 campos ao mesmo tempo.

Um jeito de isolar o campo é encontrar seu label a partir do elemento pai, no caso o `.container-campo`.

Importante notar o `$(this)` ele aponta para o elemento atual o `.parent()` vai apontar para o `.container-campo` logo acima, e por fim o `find('.descricao-campo')` vai esta apontado para o 1 unico elemento.

Segue um trecho funcional de tudo isso junto.

```js
// fixar descrição do campo
var campo = $('.campo-formulario');
var descricao = $('.descricao-campo');

campo.on('input',function(){
    var descricaoAtual = $(this).parent().find('.descricao-campo');
   if($(this).val().length > 0){
       descricaoAtual.addClass('descricao-fixa');
   } else{
       descricaoAtual.removeClass('descricao-fixa');
   }
});
```

```css
input {
outline: none;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
height: 40px;
padding: 0 15px;
font-family: 'Texto';
color: #222;
font-size: 105%;
background: none;
}

.container-campo {
width: 49%;
position: relative;
}

.descricao-campo {
position: absolute;
left: 15px;
top: 7px;
transition: all .2s;
cursor: text;
}

.descricao-fixa {
top: -10px;
left: 8px;
transition: all .2s;
z-index: 3;
background: #fff;
padding: 0 5px;
font-size: 80%;
font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus ~ .descricao-campo {
top: -10px;
left: 8px;
transition: all .2s;
z-index: 3;
background: #fff;
padding: 0 5px;
font-size: 80%;
color: dodgerblue;
font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus {
border: 1.5px solid dodgerblue;
}

.campos-dados-produto {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.dados-produto {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="campos-dados-produto">
  <div class="container-campo">
    <input type="text" name="codigo" class="campo-formulario" id="codigo" required>
    <label class="descricao-campo" for="codigo">Código</label>
  </div>
  <div class="container-campo">
    <input type="text" name="descricao" class="campo-formulario" id="descricao" required>
    <label class="descricao-campo" for="descricao">dsdds</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: essa sim funcionou corretamente! porém só tem um problema. tenho um input com mascara e a função não está se aplicando nesse campo, teria como arrumar?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `$(this).next();` para pegar o próximo elemento

```js
// fixar descrição do campo
var campo = $('.campo-formulario');

campo.on('input',function(){
    var descricao = $(this).next();

   if(campo.val().length > 0){
       descricao.addClass('descricao-fixa');
   } else{
       descricao.removeClass('descricao-fixa');
   }
});
```

```css
input {
outline: none;
width: 100%;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
height: 40px;
padding: 0 15px;
font-family: 'Texto';
color: #222;
font-size: 105%;
background: none;
}

.container-campo {
width: 49%;
position: relative;
}

.descricao-campo {
position: absolute;
left: 15px;
top: 7px;
transition: all .2s;
cursor: text;
}

.descricao-fixa {
top: -10px;
left: 8px;
transition: all .2s;
z-index: 3;
background: #fff;
padding: 0 5px;
font-size: 80%;
font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus ~ .descricao-campo {
top: -10px;
left: 8px;
transition: all .2s;
z-index: 3;
background: #fff;
padding: 0 5px;
font-size: 80%;
color: dodgerblue;
font-weight: bold;
}

input:focus {
border: 1.5px solid dodgerblue;
}

.campos-dados-produto {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.dados-produto {
width: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="campos-dados-produto">
  <div class="container-campo">
    <input type="text" name="codigo" class="campo-formulario" id="codigo" required>
    <label class="descricao-campo" for="codigo">Código</label>
  </div>
  <div class="container-campo">
    <input type="text" name="descricao" class="campo-formulario" id="descricao" required>
    <label class="descricao-campo" for="descricao">dsdds</label>
  </div>
</div>
```